# How do you archive a channel in Teams?

Tags: archiving, microsoft-teams

I know you can [archive a team](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/archive-or-delete-a-team) but I was wondering how do you archive just a single channel so that it becomes read only and hidden from the normal views?

Comment: I was able to hid a channel within a Team I am a member of by clicking the ``...` and selecting Hide.

Comment: That's not enough actually, I want it locked down so no one else can write without doing a lot of permissions work.

Comment: The only options that exist for a channel are provided when you click on the `...` button.

Answer (score 0):

I opened up my Team/Channels in Sharepoint, created an Archive folder & moved the channel there within the "In site library" of "Documents". Still testing out though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).